# What's the need for registering user-defined classes in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4

When working with a Qt GUI application, what is the need for registering a user-defined class which is not derived from Q_OBJECT ?? I am referring to the use of qRegisterMetaType("ClassName").

Thanks,
Vishnu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Qt's documentation of [QtMetaType](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmetatype.html) :

> The QMetaType class manages named
>   types in the meta-object system. The
>   class is used as a helper to marshall
>   types in QVariant and in queued
>   signals and slots connections. It
>   associates a type name to a type so
>   that it can be created and destructed
>   dynamically at run-time. Declare new
>   types with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() to
>   make them available to QVariant and
>   other template-based functions. Call
>   qRegisterMetaType() to make type
>   available to non-template based
>   functions, such as the queued signal
>   and slot connections.

Registering your custom type with qRegisterMetaType() lets you use it in signals and slots, as well as other "non-template based functions"

Comment: It's only needed for _queued_ signal/slots connections though, not for direct connections (the default).